# Transformation of random variable - lognormal distribution

Tags: self-study, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

I'm answering questions from a book that I own and I'm left scratching my head because one of my answers does not match the one provided in the book. Either the book contains a typo or I've simply done something wrong. It's a good book and it's by some quality authors, so I assume it's the latter case and hence the reason why I'm asking this question. In cases like this, I normally check if the book has an errata, but it's absent from the book's [website](http://www.cambridge.org/features/econmodelling/errata.htm). From the outset, this is not coursework; I'm not privileged enough to be on a course!

**Question in Book**

Consider the following model of asset prices, $p_{t}$, that is commonly adopted in the financial econometrics literature
$$
\ln p_{t} - \ln p_{t-1} = \alpha + u_{t}~, ~~~~u_{t} \sim iid ~ N(0,\sigma^2) ~,
$$
in which $\theta = \{\alpha, \sigma^2\}$ are unknown parameters.

Use the transformation of variable technique to show that the conditional distribution of $p_{t}$ is the log-normal distribution

$$
f(p_{t}|p_{t-1};\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}p_{t}}\exp \left[-\frac{\ln p_{t}-\ln p_{t-1}-\alpha}{2\sigma^2}\right]~~.
$$

**My Answer**
\begin{align}
f(u_{t}) &= \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left[-\frac{(\frac{u_{t}}{\sigma})^2}{2}\right]~~~~(\text{by definition of } N(0,\sigma^2))\\
         &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp \left[-\frac{u_{t}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]~~~~~(\text{by rules of exponents})\\
\end{align}
Applying the [change of variable technique](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Transformations.html), 
$$
f(p_{t}|p_{t-1};\theta) = f(u_{t})\left|\frac{\partial u_{t}}{\partial p_{t}}\right| ~,
$$
and recognizing that $u_{t} = \ln p_{t} - \ln p_{t-1} - \alpha$, yields

\begin{align}
f(p_{t}|p_{t-1};\theta) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp \left[-\frac{(\ln p_{t} - \ln p_{t-1} - \alpha)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]\left|\frac{1}{p_{t}}\right| \\
                        &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}p_{t}}\exp \left[-\frac{(\ln p_{t} - \ln p_{t-1} - \alpha)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right] ,\\
\end{align}
where we note that the determinant of 1x1 matrix is its sole entry.

**Problem**

Comparing terms, one can see that my answer differs from the book's answer with regard to the numerator in the exponent - my answer contains a squared term while the answer in the book does not.

Please point out my egregious error and give my head some rest. Cheers!

Comment: The book contains a typo, obviously, if one checks how the log-normal density is _defined_ , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: I already checked that and initially it added to the confusion (how could the book be wrong!?), yet now it serves the purpose of adding clarity to the situation - being supplemented by your comment, of course. Thanks for resolving this issue, @AlecosPapadopoulos.

Comment: I agree - that looks to me to be a straight-out typo in the book. They happen! Your answer looks right to me.